# Route planner with given times

Tags: algorithm, routes

I want to develop a route planner. For example I have 7 points or location spots. I want to set times for point 2,3 and 4. Now when I will click on route planner button my algorithm will adjust times for all 7 points comparing with those given 3 times. But should be accurate.

Is it possible to make such algorithm? And if possible can anybody suggest some algorithm sample by which I can complete this task.

Comment: From problem description it is not clear to me what the problem is. But more importantly, questions about suggestions are not, unfortunately, welcome on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for response. Basically it is about asking for idea or suggestion for such problem. If anybody has solved such problem of route planner.

Comment: How does it adjust the times? What do the times represent? For example is the time associated with point 2 and 3 the time it takes to travel from 2 to 3? Is it the same time in the reverse direction (i.e. from 3 to 2)?
If that is the meaning of the time, why would it be adjusted? Can you supply a simple worked example of what the inputs might look like along with the expected outputs. Right now your question is basically saying can I adjust some values based upon some other values? Of course the answer is yes - but more details are required.